# Java - Best way(main criteria is perfomance) to get part of a string before a given substring?

Tags: java, string

I have the string:

> This is very good string-tro:jjj for me

I want to get string

> This is very good string-

I know that I can use method `String#split` but my colleagues said that it is not best way because it is harm for performance.

Is there another way for doing that?

Comment: how about `str.substring(0,str.indexOf("-"))`?

Comment: Use the substring method. For String class, its a constant time method and is performance wise efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**String#substring**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method for that:

```
String s = "This is very good string-tro:jjj for me";
System.out.println(s.substring(0,s.indexOf("-")+1));
```

Output:

> This is very good string-